# It's possible compare payload fields in qdrant?

Tags: qdrant

I'm trying to compare values inside the payload to filter, like mongodb. I have this payload

```
{
  "openTime": "17:00",
  "closeTime": "21:00"
}
```

And I need check if the openTime is less than closeTime. It's possible compare them?

Comment: I don't think this is currently supported. You can filter less/greater than on an absolute value, but not on another field.